# SQL Server 2008 plan cache is almost always empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In order to investigate query plan usage I'm trying to understand what kind of query plan is stored in the memory.

Using this query:

```
SELECT objtype AS 'Cached Object Type', 
COUNT(*) AS 'Numberof Plans', 
SUM(CAST(size_in_bytes AS BIGINT))/1048576 AS 'Plan Cache SIze (MB)', 
AVG(usecounts) AS 'Avg Use Counts' 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
GROUP BY objtype  
ORDER BY objtype
```

I got almost empty plan cache structure. [image: almost empty plan cache].

There is 128Gb of RAM on the server and ~20% is free. SQL Server instance is not constrained by memory.

Yes basically I have Adhoc queries (not parameterized, not stored procedures).
But why SQL Server empties the query plan cache so frequent? What kind of issue do I have?

Comment: I do not have much idea.But few thing i can guess,like most of your are using WITH RECOMPILE or most of the proc are dynamic.

Comment: @KumarHarsh nope. I'm not using WITH RECOMPILE nor dymanic SQL.

Comment: Do you have "optimized for ad hoc" set?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen no. It set to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, only instance restart solved my problem. Now plan cache looks more healthy.

Answer (score 2):

If the server isn't under memory pressure then some other possibilities from the [plan caching white paper](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx) are below.

Are any of these actions scheduled frequently? Do you have auto close enabled?

> The following operations flush the entire plan cache, and therefore,
>   cause fresh compilations of batches that are submitted the first time
>   afterwards:
>
> 1. Detaching a database
> 2. Upgrading a database to SQL Server 2005
> 3. Upgrading a database to SQL Server 2008
> 4. Restoring a database
> 5. DBCC FREEPROCCACHE command
> 6. RECONFIGURE command
> 7. ALTER DATABASE ,,, MODIFY FILEGROUP command
> 8. Modifying a collation using ALTER DATABASE … COLLATE command
>
> The following operations flush the plan cache entries that refer to a
>   particular database, and cause fresh compilations afterwards.
>
> 1. DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB command
> 2. ALTER DATABASE … MODIFY NAME = command
> 3. ALTER DATABASE … SET ONLINE command
> 4. ALTER DATABASE … SET OFFLINE command
> 5. ALTER DATABASE … SET EMERGENCY command
> 6. DROP DATABASE command
> 7. When a database auto-closes
> 8. When a view is created with CHECK OPTION, the plan cache entries of the database in which the view is created are flushed.
> 9. When DBCC CHECKDB is run, a replica of the specified database is created. As part of DBCC CHECKDB's execution, some queries against the
>      replica are executed, and their plans cached. At the end of DBCC
>      CHECKDB's execution, the replica is deleted and so are the query plans
>      of the queries posed on the replica.

The following `sp_configure`/`reconfigure` operations [also clear the procedure cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx):

> - access check cache bucket count
> - access check cache quota
> - clr enabled
> - cost threshold for parallelism
> - cross db ownership chaining
> - index create memory
> - max degree of parallelism
> - max server memory
> - max text repl size
> - max worker threads
> - min memory per query
> - min server memory
> - query governor cost limit
> - query wait
> - remote query timeout
> - user options

Comment: No. These actions are not scheduled.

Comment: And autoclose is set to false.

Comment: What is the min creation time in sys.dm_exec_query_stats? Anything in the server logs around that time? Might any queries sent from applications be sending reconfigure or any of the other problem commands?

Comment: Min creation time is just now. No suspicious activity in server logs and applications do not send problem commands.

Comment: Other instances on that server feel good. And their query plan cache is quite persistent.

Comment: Are you sure max server memory on that instance isn't set to something low?

Comment: Well anyway look for signs of memory pressure e.g. with Glen Berry's queries. And if that looks healthy run a trace and look at the commands being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just about a week ago and also posted several questions. Even though I have not actually found the answer to the problem I 've got some insight on the process. And silly as it sounds SQL Server service restart helped but raised another problem - the recovery process continued for 4 hours. Seems like a pretty large transaction was in place...

[empty-plan-cache-problem](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/empty-plan-cache-problem)

[Almost empty plan cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738587/almost-empty-plan-cache?noredirect=1#comment74520047_43738587)

[Almost empty plan cache](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1873955/Almost-empty-plan-cache?Update=1#bm1874135)